# Export query using file dialog from Access into one excel workbook using VBA and Macro

Tags: ms-access, vba, spreadsheet, export-to-excel, savefiledialog

I have two queries. I would like these two queries added into one Excel (xlsx) file, but on two different Sheets, one for each query. 
This is possible with a hardcoded path:

```
Public Function Export2Queries()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "SaneringsVurdering", "C:\Users\JGJ\Desktop\Sanering.xls", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "K_SaneringLedMet", "C:\Users\JGJ\Desktop\Sanering.xls", True
End Function
```

Now I would like to combine this with a SaveAs dialog.

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function FilToSave()

Dim FlDia As FileDialog

Set FlDia = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With FlDia
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"  ' You can set outfile to a full path with a fictitious  or real file name, and the dialog will open in that folder.
    .Title = "Please name the file you want to save"
    If .Show = True Then
        FilName = .SelectedItems(1)


    Else
        MsgBox "No file selected. Process cancelled"
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        FilToSave = "Cancelled"
        Exit Function
        End If
End With

FilToSave = FilName

End Function
```

Got it to work with the above solution.

```
Public Function Export2Queries()
Dim savefile As String
savefile = FilToSave
If savefile <> "Cancelled" Then
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "SaneringsVurdering", savefile, True
End If
End Function
```

Now this code works for exporting a query/table to a wanted to location with dialog prompt.

Comment: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` is a simple method, that can't be expanded to what you request. You'll have to use automation and open an Excel instance to manipulate the worksheets.

Comment: I managed to create a module that can add the first query on sheet 1 and the second query on sheet two.

`Public Function Export2Queries()

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Concatenate", "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ExportTest.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SaneringTilImport", "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ExportTest.xlsx", True
End Function`
But a prompt for location instead of hardcode, would be nice. But you say this isn't possible?

Comment: Oh, forgot about that last parameter. A class for OpenFileDialog can be found here at Karsten Pries: [Klassenmodul FileDialog](http://www.kpries.de/)

Comment: My german isn't really good. And when I open his code it says there is a conversion problem as I'm using Access 2010 64-bit. Basically I need to replace this "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ExportTest.xlsx" with a SaveLocationPrompt.

Comment: The second and third download should cover Access 64-bit. If not, drop Karsten a note.

Comment: Edited whole code. Now I've got an error which I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: `wbDest` isn't declared or initialized anywhere, thus the error. I'd say you should use `FilName` as parameter for `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just edited the code above, it now work perfectly :)